# Need to format an email in Excel or access

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-access

I have an exported excel file from MS ACCESS that is fine but some don't have email addresses, But they are all the same that is, Lastname. (put in a '.')Firstname@dcf.nj.gov
I have a formula that will create the name as it appear but we need to flip it. As it appears is lastname,firstname. This will create the exact. =SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,",",".")," ","")&"@dcrdf.ny.gov"
But we need that the email is: Firstname.lastname all we have to divide is that comma in the original data as (lastname,firsname)
Data

```
Name                email
Smit,Joe           currently blank
Smit,Jane          Jane.Smit@dcrdf.ny.gov
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the formula:

```
=MID(A1,FIND(",",A1,1)+1,9999)&"."&LEFT(A1,FIND(",",A1,1)-1)&"@dcf.nj.gov"
```